# What is the correct MIME type for a CSV File created by Excel with semicolon as separator

Tags: excel, csv, mime, regional-settings

I work in Switzerland, where the semicolon `;` is the "official" list separator in Windows' regional settings.

Excel uses this separator when creating CSV files.

In RFC 4180 the CSV file is defined as *comma* separated and has the mime type of `text/csv` associated. My file does not conform to this definition.

I'm using `application/vnd.ms-excel` instead, but I'm not satisfied by declaring it an "Excel" file, since it's an application independent *semicolon-separated* file.

What would the correct MIME type be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no official mime-type for a semicolon-separated file. This is not surprising - the mime type also does not specify the character-encoding, for example.

You could simply use text/plain (since the file is after all simply a text file), but I presume that you want to use a particular mime type because you want the browser/OS to open it in an "appropriate" application. (This format is only really suitable for processing by an application of some sort).

I would think that in 90% of cases that appropriate application will be Excel. For the few users who don't have Excel but do have an Excel-a-like, you may find that the Excel-a-like application registers itself as able to consume Excel files, and so it may all just work as you wanted?